# Jquery Datatables get row data as string or object on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm attempting to get a row of data based on button click event. I can manage to find the row and read the results as text, but I want the data cast as a string or an object. Below is my current code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "SympsService.asmx/GetSymptoms",
  method: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    organ_name: "toes"
  }),
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data) {
    var sympList = 'GetSymptoms' ? JSON.parse(data.d) : data.d;
    createDataTable('#symptomsTable', sympList);

    function createDataTable(target, data) {

      $(target).DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        info: false,
        data: data,
        columnDefs: [{
          targets: [-1],
          render: function() {
            return "<button type='button'>" + ('Choose') + "</button>"
          }
        }],
        columns: [{
          'data': 'Sympt',
          'title': 'toes Symptoms'
        }, {
          'data': null,
          'title': 'Action'
        }]
      });
    }

    $('#symptomsTable').on("click", "tbody button", function() {
      var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").text(); //this show perfectly
      var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").data(); //this show undefined
      var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").toString(); //this show {object Object}
      console.log(id);
    })
  },

});
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the data object for the whole row:

```
$("#symptomsTable').DataTable().rows($(this).closest("tr")).data()
```

to find it for the particular cell:

```
$("#symptomsTable").DataTable().cells($(this).closest("td").siblings().eq(0)).data()
```

Comment: I tried but it shows Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable(...).rows is not a function.
and for the particular cell it shows: [context: Array[1], selector: Object, ajax: Object]
@Bindrid

Comment: Change your dataTable to DataTable. I get and error on little d too

Comment: I change that.but now show this: [context: Array[1], selector: Object, ajax: Object] for both.

Comment: if g = $("#symptomsTable").DataTable().cells($(this).closest("td").siblings().eq(0)).data() what is in g[0]

Comment: Aslo, do you know how to use debugger  statement recognized by most browsers that will stop your code and let you examine objects, variables, etc?